# How do I make overset text automatically flow into adjacent columns, in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, typography, page-layout, typesetting

Is it possible **[in Photoshop]** to make overset text flow into an adjacent column, once the first text box is full?

ex. I have two three columns [A,B and C] and a surplus of copy. Once column A is full, I want excess copy to populate column B. If column B becomes full, I would like column C to be populated with any remaining copy and [if necessary] so forth.

This is something that's relatively trivial InDesign but I'm unaware of a way to do this in Photoshop. **Thanks in advance for your help**.

Comment: Photoshop is a raster graphics editor, not a typesetting application. If you want to do typesetting, use a typesetter.

Comment: That's what I was a afraid of. Thanks @MartinSchröder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but pretty sure this isn't possible in PS.

If you're working with that much type that you need to use many text boxes, ideally it should be done in InDesign or Illustrator.

Answer (score 1):

I created a Photoshop script that does what you want. Download [here](http://bereza.cz/ps/).

[image]